# RabbitMQ on Windows - enable the Firehose on service restart

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Is there a way to setup RabbitMQ in a way that the Firehose is autamatically enabled (for a single virtual host preferably) after a Windows or RabbitMQ service restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Running RabbitMQ Server as a Service (on Windows)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html#running-windows-service) doc,

> The service runs using the rabbitmq-service.bat script in sbin.

So you can customize it to get desired behavior.

Comment: `rabbitmq-service.bat` just register with the help of `erlsrv` Windows service for RabbitMQ. It doesn't executed every time RabbitMQ service starts, stops, etc. The original idea was to modify start process to enable firehose (maybe utilize some code from `rabbitmqctl.bat`).